# How to completely remove Bitcoin Lightning from Raspberry Pi

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, lightning-network, raspberry-pi, lightning-network-daemon

I finished the installation of Bitcoin Core and Lightning but somehow i messed up with the certificates and the creation of the wallet and now im struggling to run lightning with the right users and the wallet creation was simply a mess, therefore how to remove all traces of lightning from my pi and start the installation from scratch?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know which Lightning Network node your are running but since you are talking about bitcoin core and not btcd I assume you run c-lightning. There you should be able to remove everything with `make uninstall`

Comment: You can't be sure, LND also support Bitcoin Core nowadays.

Comment: @KristapsKaupe for what its worth, `lnd` has been able to run on top of `bitcoind` for a long time, I set it up probably ~10 months ago. From what I've read, it works better with `btcd`, but I didn't have much trouble.